# Find the basis for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Find the basis of $ V=\{(a, b, c) \in \mathbb {R}^3 \mid a+2b-2c=0\}$

I got $(2, 0, 1)$, $(-2, 1, 0)$ as an answer, but I though that $\dim (V) $  has to be equal to $ n $ for $\mathbb {R}^n $?

Comment: Your answer is correct. Note that $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: @Mi Well, yes it is: $\;\dim V=2=\dim\Bbb R^2\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that there isn't "*the* basis" of $V$. A vector space usually has a lot of bases, you just want to find one of them. Next you are right, in this case $\dim(V)=2$, and also $\dim(\mathbb R^n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. However, $V$ is a *proper subspace* of $\mathbb R^3$, so it will be of dimension *less* than $3$, in this case $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You already have good answers, but none mentions yet that if you know about scalar products, you can interpret the equation giving $V$ as asking the vector $(a,b,c)$ to be orthogonal to the fixed vector $(1,2,-2)$, which helps giving a geometric interpretation of $V$ as a plane in three-dimensional space -- and gives another way to find **a** basis (singular!)